# How to configure Eclipse for Phpcloud

Tags: php, eclipse, php-ide

I am looking for a guidline for step by step configuration Eclipse with PHPcloud. phpcloud have got a quick start guideline covering zend studio, Netbeans and PHP storm.

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers , Version: 3.0.2

PHPcould: https://my.phpcloud.com